# What is the syntaxis ##*/ for?

Tags: bash

What is the difference between
`${i##*/}` and `${i}`?

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/pull/2551/files

Comment: Manual page: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Also covered in [BashFAQ #73](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) and [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)

Comment: See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).  Also see the [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) section of the POSIX [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) document.